# How to get Application configuration keys?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, config, environment

Is there any way to get application configuration values, that was setted in "config/environments/development" ?

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.my_value = "Test"  
end
```

MyApp::Application object is accessible from the app, but, this code does't works:

```
MyApp::Application.config.my_value
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Rails.application.config.my_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using one of the many Gems out there to handle custom configurations in Rails apps.

Personally I use [rails_config](https://github.com/railsjedi/rails_config) a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this plugin by Mislav:
https://github.com/mislav/choices